# KineticsJs auto resize canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

My autoresize canvas not works with **kineticjs**, the console say me that canvas.width and canvas.height is not defined.

Any people could help me.

Thank you .

Put the function and the call down.

```
function resize() {
    console.log("ddddddddddddd");
//stage.setWidth((window.innerWidth / 100) * 80);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('Contenedor');
    console.log(canvas, canvas.height, canvas.width);
    if(window.innerWidth < 1280){
       var canvasRatio = canvas.height / canvas.width;
       console.log(canvasRatio);
       var windowRatio = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth;
       console.log(windowRatio);
       var width;
       var height;

       if (windowRatio < canvasRatio) {
           height = window.innerHeight;
           width = height / canvasRatio;
       } else {
           width = window.innerWidth;
           height = width * canvasRatio;
       }

       canvas.style.width = (parseFloat(width)*0.75) + 'px';
       canvas.style.height = (parseFloat(height)*0.75) + 'px';
   }else{
    canvas.style.width=987+'px';
    canvas.style.height=544+'px';
   }    
};
window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is set the height of the canvas with respect to the width.
And use  stage.setScale() and stage.setSize() to dynamically change the size of the stage

```
function resize() {
        var canvasWidthRatio = 0.6;        // canvas width to viewport width ratio
        var viewPortWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var canvasWidth = viewPortWidth * canvasWidthRatio;
        var canvasHeight = canvasWidth * 0.6,
            scale = stage.getScale(),
            stageWidth = stage.getWidth(),
            stageHeight = stage.getHeight(),
            scaleFactor = Math.min(canvasWidth / stageWidth, canvasHeight / stageHeight),
            newScale = scale * scaleFactor;
        stage.setScale(newScale);
        stage.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        stage.draw();
}
window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
```

Comment: Thank you. I push that function the problem is that the stage scale but the imagen insideand the other images go to 0.0. Realease the same than a crop.

Comment: Hello. I check with console and see that newScale = scale * scaleFactor; say me undefined, it is posible that you could not multiply a obj with a float?

Comment: you can initially set 1 for the stage.getScale();

Answer (score 1):

I think kineticjs sets the canvas dimensions.

set the stage width and height and don't touch the canvas directly.

Comment: Yes I think that you are right, when I create the canvas via tml5, code down, this function worked, but when I past to Kineticjs this not works, but I think that are a solution of this.

<canvas id='canvas' width="987" height="544">
    Canvas not supported
</canvas>

Answer (score 0):

Hello and sorry my bad english, also thank you to help me. I work with the code of VijayB, but with his code I have problems with multiply the object scale with a float.. I realease a few changes and for me are working.

I put the code for someone that have my own problem.

```
function resize() {
    var __canvasWidthRatio = 0.6;    
    console.log( __canvasWidthRatio) ;  // canvas width to viewport width ratio
    var __viewPortWidth = window.innerWidth;
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
    var __canvasWidth = __viewPortWidth * __canvasWidthRatio;
    console.log(__canvasWidth);
    var aspec = 769 / 544;
    var __canvasHeight =  aspec *__canvasWidth * __canvasWidthRatio;
    var     __scale = ui.stage.getScale();
    var     __stageWidth = ui.stage.getWidth();
    var     __stageHeight = ui.stage.getHeight();
    var     __scaleFactor = Math.min( __canvasWidth /  __stageWidth,  __canvasHeight /  __stageHeight);
    stage.escala=  __scale.x *__scaleFactor;
    ui.scale=__scale.x *__scaleFactor;
    stage.setScale(stage.escala,stage.escala);
    stage.setSize(__canvasWidth, __canvasHeight);
    stage.draw();
}
window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
```